# Stored procedure works, but gives invalid column in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldataadapter

When I am running the stored procedure below in SMSS, it works and returns a nice result.

SQL:

```
EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[xxxxxx_EnergiAllTags]
    @SegmentResponseID = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
```

But when I am trying to run the stored procedure from my C# code, I get an error:

> Invalid column name 'Value'

This is my code:

```
 public DataSet GetQuery(string batchNr)
 {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("xxxxxxxx");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("xxxxxx_EnergiAllTags", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SegmentResponseID", batchNr));

        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        command.CommandTimeout = 60000;

        try
        {
            da.Fill(ds1);
            return ds1;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string ex = e.Message;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone that might have a clue help me figure out what the problem is?

****Update as Req*****

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxxxxx_EnergiAllTags]
    @SegmentResponseID AS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #temp (TagName NVARCHAR(MAX),
                        StartValue NVARCHAR(MAX),
                        EndValue NVARCHAR(MAX),
                        Usage NVARCHAR(MAX)
                       )

    INSERT INTO #temp 
        EXEC [dbo].[xxxxxx_EnergyTagForBatch] @BatchID = @SegmentResponseID, 
@TagName = 'T06C02D01E02FQ000.PV'

    INSERT INTO #temp 
        EXEC [dbo].[xxxxxx_EnergyTagForBatch] @BatchID = @SegmentResponseID, 
@TagName = 'T06C02D01E02FQ001.PV'

    SELECT * From #temp
    DROP TABLE #temp
END
```

Comment: Can you share the code of `xxxxxx_EnergiAllTags` and what output do you expect it to return?

Comment: I think we need to see the stored procedure's code as well. Do you have a column called `Value`? if so, try to wrap it with square brackets - `[Value]`.

Comment: Value is a keyword in t-sql, use square brackets for that type names, ex: [Value].

Comment: Are you sure both are running in same database ?

Comment: Post have been updated.

Comment: The problem not in this SP. You are calling two other SPs from it, check them.

Comment: If i run the other sp xxxxxx_EnergyTagForBatch from my c# code it works fine.

Comment: Can you temporarily comment out the INSERTs and try again? All the code from the first INSERT until before the SELECT on the #temp. It's an easy way to find out if the problem lies in your C#, in the procedure you shown us or in the called procedure.

Comment: What is the output from xxxxxx_EnergyTagForBatch - does it exactly match the temp table schema?

Comment: Your temp table doesn't have a column "Value". Where exactly do you see the error? Any InnerExceptions that give more info?

Comment: not i found the error, there was a #temp table in sp1 and sp2 i was calling, and it the sql had trouble figuring out which temp table belonged to what sp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i have figured out the problem.

The 2 SP i have both had a temp table called #temp and while i believe they should be localized to each instance, they were not, and mixed, and by that time they gave an error.

Solution, make sure that there are not temp tables with the same name using in the string of stored-procedure you might call.